# How to store color codes within [Int] Swift

Tags: swift, colors

I need to store color codes into an `[Int]` array, but have big differences between Java and Swift. Let me know how to convert this code to Swift.

**Java code**

```
int[] colorArgbs = {0xFF000000, 0xFFffffff, 0xFF00ffff, 0xFF6060ff};
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(colorArgbs[0]) + " " + 
                    Integer.valueOf(colorArgbs[1]) + " " +
                    Integer.valueOf(colorArgbs[2]) + " " +
                    Integer.valueOf(colorArgbs[3]));

//Output is: -16777216 -1 -16711681 -10460929
```

**With Swift**

```
var test : [Int] = [0xFF000000,0xFFffffff,0xFF00ffff,0xFF6060ff]
print(test)  //Output: [4278190080, 4294967295, 4278255615, 4284506367]
```

I tried to remove the `FF` character above, but I don't like the result.

```
var test1 : [Int] = [0x000000,0xffffff,0x00ffff,0x6060ff]
print(test1)  //Output: [0, 16777215, 65535, 6316287]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't store colour codes as `Int` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You are testing on a **64-bit** device, where `Int` is `Int64` by default and does not overflow after 2,147,483,647. If you want to explicitly work with **32-bit** `Int` values, you could use `Int32`:

```
var test: [Int32] = [0xFF000000,0xFFffffff,0xFF00ffff,0xFF6060ff]
print(test) //Output: [-16777216, -1, -16711681, -10460929]
```

But you **can't**, because this generates a compiler warning.

> Integer literal '4284506367' overflows when stored into 'Int32'

Why?

Because overflow is **not a good thing**, nor it should be used in a product. Don't use **32-bit** `Int`s to store color codes which are larger. Use `Int64` for this purpose.